# Case when returning empty result rows

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

For an SSRS report I made a query returning the revenue of 3 different years by using Case when based on user input.

```
DECLARE @Year as int
Set @Year = 2018
DECLARE @Period as int
Set @Period = 1

SELECT Account
, Customer
, CustomerDescription
, Article
, ArticleDescription
, Sum (Case when Year = @Year -2 then NNNRevenue Else 0 End) as RevenueP2
, Sum (Case when Year = @Year -1 then NNNRevenue Else 0 End) as RevenuePY
, Sum (Case when Year = @Year then NNNRevenue Else 0 End) as RevenueCY
 FROM [PP_Test].[dbo].[History]
 WHERE Line = 'Inkoopartikel'
And Period = @Period
 GROUP BY Account, customer, CustomerDescription, Article, ArticleDescription
```

Sample result:

```
Account  Customer  CustomerDescription  Article  ArticleDescription  RevenueP2   RevenuePY  RevenueCY 
A        A         CustomerA            1234     Transport           0           0          0
A        A         CustomerA            2345     Croissant           12,15       0          14578,87
```

Now when I have an article which was sold in 2015 it shows up with 0 in my 3 Revenue columns. I would like to eliminate those null/0 rows.

I've found a solution for mysql by adding the following

```
 HAVING RevenueP2 <> 0
```

This however doesn't work for Server management studio as I cannot reference the new column.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by two ways

1. Put Aggregate function in HAVING Clause

   ```
   HAVING Sum (Case when Year = @Year -2 then NNNRevenue Else 0 End) <> 0
   ```
2. Using Derive Table concept

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM(
     Paste your query here wihtout where clause
   )m
   Where RevenueP2 <> 0
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
having Sum (Case when Year = @Year -2 then NNNRevenue Else 0 End) <> 0
```